# Grub for dual-boot elementary OS with Windows 10

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, elementaryos

**Main goal:** Elementary OS & Windows 10 dual boot with GRUB bootloader on a 200GB SSD

**Problem:** System booting directly into elementary os

**Steps I've taken:**

1. Installed Windows 10 whilst setting the *System* (EFI) partition 512Mb
2. Installed elementary OS with the *System* partition of Windows as */boot/efi*

*At this point my partition table looks like the following:*

| Name | Description |
| --- | --- |
| sda1 | System (`/boot/efi` in Linux) |
| sda2 | MRS |
| sda3 | Primary |
| sda4 | Recovery |
| sda5 | `/` |
| sda6 | `[SWAP]` |
| sda7 | `/home` |

3. Enabled `os-prober` and run

```
grub-install /dev/sda1
update-grub
```

both of which finish without any errors, detecting both Elementary OS and Windows 10. After that, I can see all three entries in `efibootmgr -v`:

- GRUB ([...]\EFI\GRUB\shimx64.efi)
- Windows Boot Manager ([...]\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)
- elementary OS 6 Odin ([...]\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)

4. Configured the grub boot order and auto-boot time (10s) in grub-customizer

My system uefi boot order is currently GRUB, Microsoft Boot Manager, elementary OS and manually booting in Microsoft Boot Manager works, so it's impossible that grub is just failing, causing the system to fall into elementary OS.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your Windows OS to your **Grub** loader, but be careful, if you are using hibernation or sleeping in your Windows, you won't be able to use it, because after restart you will fall into Grub and when you choose Windows it will load Windows from scratch.

run `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`  
to see if there is any Windows entry